# Questions on zookeeper: barrier implementation and sequence node

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have 2 questions on zookeeper:

> Barries implementation

https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/recipes.html#sc_recipes_eventHandles

Why the 4th step is necessary? If the client waits for a delete event for the barrier node, when the event is triggered, why the client still needs to reissue the **exists()** call?

> Sequence node

Does zookeeper guarantees that the numbers appended to a sequence nodes' names are **consecutive**, and **beginning from 0**? Even if mixed with the Ephemeral attribute?

For example, if  */test*  is a newly created node, the sequence child nodes must be something like: */test/xxx_00000000000*, */test/xxx_00000000001*, */test/xxx_00000000002*...    Beginning from */test/xxx_00000000000* and */test/xxx_00000000001* will never miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question :

There can be an arbitrary amount of clients watching, one will enter, and for the others, exists() will return true again, hence the need to retest.

Second question :

I think yes, they will be consecutive and starting from 0 in all scenariis. I don't have a good source for this, but I used sequential nodes in a variety of situations (including ephemeral sequential), and never saw another behaviour.

Comment: If all clients wait for the delete event for the barrier node, and when the node has been deleted, all clients should be notified, and any call to exists() should return false. Since the node has been deleted, how can any clients get true for the exists() call?

Comment: I'm assuming the first client to get the notification will enter and reput the barrier up for others to see.

Comment: I still don't understand why the first client should reput the barrier? In my understanding, if the barrier disappears, i.e. the node has been deleted, then all clients should continue processing. So there's no need to reput the barrier. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The whole point of a barrier is to restrict access to one client at a time. So I'm assuming you don't want all client processing at the same time, else, you just don't need a barrier in the first place.

Comment: In my scenario, I need all clients wait for a resource, when that resource is ready, all clients continue processing. So I need set the barrier first, and remove the barrier when the resource is ready. On the other hand, if I need restrict access to one client at a time, I won't use barrier, instead, I'll use a distribute lock.

Comment: Ok :) you just need a semaphore, and in that case indeed you don't need to recheck the exists() after the notification :)